# How to replicate a large MySQL database (on a server) to a local SQLite database (1 way sync)

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlite, synchronization, replication

I have a MySQL database on a Windows server (the "Master"), which should store tens of GB (with InnoDB compression), with new records added on a daily basis.

For speed purposes, I would like to replicate the tables on remote computers (the "Slaves"), running Windows or Linux, which are doing data analysis (hence no concurrency issue locally).
I thought of using a SQLite database for this purpose, that would contain a synchronized snapshot of the Master.

So far, I have been using Dropbox (for teams) to sync csv files but delta sync would probably not work with huge database files.

I would therefore appreciate your input to determine the best way to perform the replication between these two different engines. In particular, it should be able to detect changes at a field level to limit the amount of data that needs to be transferred!

So far, I am aware of the following possibilities:

- [DBSync for SQLite & MySQL](http://dbconvert.com/convert-sqlite-to-mysql-sync.php)
- Maybe [greplicator](http://www.ywsystems.com/) and [dbForge Data Compare for SQL Server](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/)

Answer (score 0):

### *Tap - Tap - Tap* -- Taps!

The guys at Heroku wrote a nice little Ruby script to help with just this scenario. I think you'll find it fairly well battle-tested and in general just a nice little database agnostic 'sync' tool.

https://github.com/ricardochimal/taps

http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/

### Beware the caveats

With any good piece of magical software there's caveats, it's good to be upfront about them:

```
**Known Issues**
```

- Foreign key constraints get lost in the schema transfer
- Tables without primary keys will be incredibly slow to transfer. This is due to it being inefficient having large offset values in
  queries.
- Multiple schemas are currently not supported

Thanks,

Anuj

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQLyog Data synchronization tool](http://www.webyog.com/en/) using which you can specify a valid SQL WHERE clause for the table to sync only those rows that fulfill the WHERE clause.